# FreeForm installation Error - Table 'DATABASE.exp_freeform_fieldtypes' doesn't exist

Tags: solspace-freeform, solspace

When trying to install either FreeForm Lite OR FreeForm Pro version 4.2.3, the following database error occurs, making it impossible to install the plugin.

There are no references to any tables within the database so it's trying to delete something which doesn't exist and failing.

ExpressionEngine version 2.10.1

```
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146

Table 'staging_camden_brewery.exp_freeform_fieldtypes' doesn't exist

DELETE FROM `exp_freeform_fieldtypes` WHERE `default_field` = 'y'

Filename: third_party/freeform/models/freeform_model.php

Line Number: 538
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it working by opening up and running the SQL commands inside **db.freeform.sql** one by one. Then installing once all the tables were in the database:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_forms` (
    `form_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `form_name`                     varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `form_label`                    varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `default_status`                varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `notify_user`                   char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    `notify_admin`                  char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    `user_email_field`              varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `user_notification_id`          int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `admin_notification_id`         int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `admin_notification_email`      text,
    `form_description`              text,
    `field_ids`                     text,
    `field_order`                   text,
    `template_id`                   int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `composer_id`                   int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `author_id`                     int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `entry_date`                    int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `edit_date`                     int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `settings`                      text,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`form_id`),
    KEY                             (`form_name`),
    KEY                             (`site_id`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_composer_layouts` (
    `composer_id`                   int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `composer_data`                 text,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `preview`                       char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    `entry_date`                    int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `edit_date`                     int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`composer_id`),
    KEY                             (`preview`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_fields` (
    `field_id`                      int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `field_name`                    varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `field_label`                   varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `field_type`                    varchar(50)         NOT NULL DEFAULT 'text',
    `settings`                      text,
    `author_id`                     int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `entry_date`                    int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `edit_date`                     int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `required`                      char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    `submissions_page`              char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    `moderation_page`               char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    `composer_use`                  char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    `field_description`             text,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`field_id`),
    KEY                             (`field_name`),
    KEY                             (`site_id`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_fieldtypes` (
    `fieldtype_id`                  int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `fieldtype_name`                varchar(250),
    `settings`                      text,
    `default_field`                 char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    `version`                       varchar(12),
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`fieldtype_id`),
    KEY                             (`fieldtype_name`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_composer_templates` (
    `template_id`                   int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `template_name`                 varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `template_label`                varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `template_description`          text,
    `enable_template`               char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    `template_data`                 text,
    `param_data`                    text,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`template_id`),
    KEY                             (`template_name`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_notification_templates` (
    `notification_id`               int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `notification_name`             varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `notification_label`            varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `notification_description`      text,
    `wordwrap`                      char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    `allow_html`                    char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    `from_name`                     varchar(150)        NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `from_email`                    varchar(250)        NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `reply_to_email`                varchar(250)        NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `email_subject`                 varchar(128)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default',
    `include_attachments`           char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    `template_data`                 text,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`notification_id`),
    KEY                             (`notification_name`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_params` (
    `params_id`                     int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `entry_date`                    int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `data`                          text,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`params_id`),
    KEY                             (`entry_date`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_preferences` (
    `preference_id`                 int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `preference_name`               varchar(80),
    `preference_value`              text,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`preference_id`),
    KEY                             (`preference_name`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_user_email` (
    `email_id`                      int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `author_id`                     int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `ip_address`                    varchar(40)         NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `entry_date`                    int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `form_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `entry_id`                      int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `email_count`                   int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `email_addresses`               text,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`email_id`),
    KEY                             (`ip_address`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_file_uploads` (
    `file_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `form_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `entry_id`                      int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `field_id`                      int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `server_path`                   varchar(750),
    `filename`                      varchar(250),
    `extension`                     varchar(20),
    `filesize`                      int(10)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`file_id`),
    KEY                             (`entry_id`),
    KEY                             (`field_id`),
    KEY                             (`extension`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_multipage_hashes` (
    `hash_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `form_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `entry_id`                      int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `hash`                          varchar(32)         NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
    `ip_address`                    varchar(40)         NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `date`                          int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `edit`                          char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
    `data`                          text,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`hash_id`),
    KEY                             (`hash`),
    KEY                             (`ip_address`),
    KEY                             (`site_id`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_freeform_email_logs` (
    `id`                            int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `site_id`                       int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
    `date`                          int(10) unsigned    NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    `type`                          varchar(250)        NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
    `success`                       char(1)             NOT NULL DEFAULT 'y',
    `from`                          text,
    `from_name`                     text,
    `to`                            text,
    `subject`                       text,
    `message`                       text,
    `debug_info`                    text,
    PRIMARY KEY                     (`id`)
) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same error.  Interestingly I can install it on my local MAMP install, but not on the staging site, so it could be an environment issue.

Comment: Hey Joobs, yeah I had the exact same issue, with MAMP running it fine and staging / production not playing ball.

I managed to get it working by opening up and running the SQL commands inside db.freeform.sql one by one. Then installing once all the tables were in the database.